Returning a chain with a custom runnable in Langchain to use with Langserve
I am trying to create a custom chain that would be served via my langserve API and would accept configurable fields via the per_req_config_modifier that helps out in parsing headers from the API request and passing them on to the custom runnable class. I have defined the class like this so far which worked when I was using my own OpenAI API key to test. However, to enable passing the key from the request headers would require me to pass the key via config modifier as defined below. I have modified the class like so:

class PerUserQuery(RunnableSerializable):
    """
    A custom runnable that returns a list of documents for the given user.

    The runnable is configurable by the user, and the search results are
    filtered by the user ID.
    """

    user_id: Optional[str]
    openai_api_key: Optional[str]
    vectorstore: Optional[VectorStore]

    class Config:
        # Allow arbitrary types since VectorStore is an abstract interface
        # and not a pydantic model
        arbitrary_types_allowed = True

    def get_rag_chain(self, query):
        self.vectorstore = get_vectorstore(self.openai_api_key)
        retriever = self.vectorstore.similarity_search(
            query, k=5, filter={"user_id": {"$eq": self.user_id}}
        )

        def format_docs(docs):
            return "\n\n".join(doc.page_content for doc in docs)

        return {
            "context": format_docs(retriever),
            "question": RunnablePassthrough(),
        }

    def invoke(
        self, input: str, config: Optional[RunnableConfig] = None, **kwargs
    ) -> List[Document]:
        retriever = self.get_rag_chain(query=input)
        return retriever

This works with the chain:
per_user_retriever = PerUserQuery(
    user_id=None,  # Placeholder ID that will be replaced by the per_req_config_modifier
    openai_api_key=None,
    vectorstore=None,
).configurable_fields(
    user_id=ConfigurableField(
        id="user_id",
        name="User ID",
        description="The user ID to use for the retriever",
    ),
    openai_api_key=ConfigurableField(
        id="openai_api_key",
        name="OpenAI API Key",
        description="The OpenAI API key to use for the retriever",
    ),
    vectorstore=ConfigurableField(
        id="vectorstore",
        name="Vectorstore",
        description="The vectorstore to use for the retriever",
    ),
)

prompt = hub.pull("rlm/rag-prompt")
llm = get_llm(assume_api_key)

chain = per_user_retriever | prompt | llm | StrOutputParser()

However I am unable to extend the chain like so:
def get_rag_chain(self, query):
        self.vectorstore = get_vectorstore(self.openai_api_key)
        retriever = self.vectorstore.similarity_search(
            query, k=5, filter={"user_id": {"$eq": self.user_id}}
        )

        def format_docs(docs):
            return "\n\n".join(doc.page_content for doc in docs)

        prompt = hub.pull("rlm/rag-prompt")
        llm = get_llm(self.openai_api_key)

        return (
            {
                "context": format_docs(retriever),
                "question": RunnablePassthrough(),
            }
            | prompt
            | llm
        )

hoping to use it as:
chain = per_user_retriever | StrOutputParser()

Instead I get the error:
TypeError: Expected a Runnable, callable or dict.Instead got an unsupported type: <class 'str'>

Any help with this would be appreciated

This question is similar to: TypeError when chaining Runnables in LangChain: Expected a Runnable, callable or dict. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The issue is context is of type str. Pass in a lambda function instead:
rag_chain = ({
        "context": lambda x: format_docs(retriever),
        "question": RunnablePassthrough(),
    }
    | prompt
    | llm
)
return rag_chain

same question is here
